# How to install packages when dependency is already installed from PPA?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dependencies, ppa

I'm trying to install `libgdal-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

But it has unmet dependencies: `Depends: libpng-dev`

Which itself cannot be installed because:

```
libpng12-dev : Depends: libpng12-0 (= 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.2.54-5x0~ppa is to be installed
```

This package is installed from a `ppa`:

```
dpkg -s libpng12-0 | grep ^Maintainer
Maintainer: Otto Meier <otto@kesselgulasch.org>
```

([via](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8560/how-do-i-find-out-which-repository-a-package-comes-from))

I want to keep that [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) as it provides GIMP 2.9.

---

**Question**:

- How can I install `libpng12-dev` and `libgdal-dev` (maybe ignoring or manually changing certain dependencies) ?
- or generally: How to install packages when dependency is already installed in another version from PPA ?

---

(Hint: Installing GIMP with Snap is neither [preferred](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000781/is-there-any-way-to-make-snap-installed-apps-look-more-native) nor [possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040194/how-to-use-snap-packages-when-home-is-not-home-user))

---

---

**What I tried:**

I installed `libpng12-dev` ignoring `libpng12-0` dependecy 
([via](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies)):

```
apt download libpng12-dev
sudo dpkg --ignore-depends=libpng12-0 -i libpng12-dev_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

This worked.
Also, `libgdal-dev` still had unmnet dependencies, so I did the same:

```
sudo apt install libgdal-dev
sudo dpkg --ignore-depends=libpng12-0 -i libgdal-dev_2.2.2+dfsg-1~xenial1_amd64.deb #png12-dev_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgdal-dev:
 libgdal-dev depends on libarmadillo-dev; however:
  Package libarmadillo-dev is not installed.
 libgdal-dev depends on libcurl4-gnutls-dev | libcurl-ssl-dev; however:
  Package libcurl4-gnutls-dev is not installed.
  Package libcurl-ssl-dev is not installed.
 libgdal-dev depends on libdap-dev; however:
  Package libdap-dev is not installed.
 libgdal-dev depends on libepsilon-dev; however:
  Package libepsilon-dev is not installed.
 libgdal-dev depends on libfreexl-dev; however:
  Package libfreexl-dev is not installed.
 libgdal-dev depends on libfyba-dev; however:
  Package libfyba-dev is not installed.
 libgdal-dev depends on libgeos-dev; however:
  Package libgeos-dev is not installed.
 libgdal-dev depends on libgeotiff-dev; however:
  Package libgeotiff-dev is not installed.
 libgdal-dev depends on libgif-dev; however:
  Package libgif-dev is not installed.
 libgdal-dev depends on libhdf4-alt-dev; however:
  Package libhdf4-alt-dev is not installed
```

So, I stopped here and fixed the situation again:

```
sudo dpkg -r libgdal-dev
sudo dpkg -r libpng12-dev
```

Comment: forgot about that, updated tags.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Indeed that is the root cause of my problem => Leftovers from the ppa installed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

@dsstorefile1 gave the right hint to fix my issue:

The ppa I linked in the question *was* made for 16.04 when I installed it, but it changed and the the maintainer removed most packages for `xenial` including `libpng12-0`.

---

So this is how I fixed the situation:

- Remove the ppa using `ppa-purge`:

  ```
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
  ```
- Downgrade the `libpng12-0` package to the version from the official repos:

  ```
  sudo apt install libpng12-0=1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1
  ```
- Install `libgdal-dev`:

  ```
  sudo apt install libgdal-dev
  ```

---

I also noticed that following packages are also leftovers from that ppa:

```
libbabl-0.1-0
libgegl-0.3-0
liblcms2
libwebp6
```

So, I also downgraded/removed these:

```bsh
sudo apt install libbabl-0.1-0=0.1.16-1
sudo apt install libgegl-0.3-0=0.3.4-1ubuntu2
sudo apt install liblcms2-2=2.6-3ubuntu2
sudo apt remove libwebp6 #no candidate from repos
```

Comment: While this fixes my issue, the general question is still open.

Comment: i followed your steps and i cannot get `libpng12-0` package for artful, if that package for xenial, how i can get it sir?

Comment: First of all artful is [EOL](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18032/eol-notice-artful-aardvark-17-10-reached-end-of-life-on-july-19-2018). Then, why do you follow my steps at all if you don't have the same issue?